# Cutoff Frequency Calculation for Basic Multimode / State-Variable Filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-filters, frequency-response

I am working with a basic multimode / state-variable filter topology which combines highpass, lowpass, and bandpass outputs. I am wondering if there is a formula I can use to calculate cutoff frequency based on sample rate and the various coefficients.

Here is the DSP snippet of the code I am working with. Cutoff frequency is set by the variable "c". I want to find a formula to calculate the cutoff based on the value of "c" and the sample rate.

```
void read_filter(T in){
    T sig = in;
    T c = coef.get();
    T r = res.get();
    sig -= filt[lp];
    sig -= filt[bp] * r;
    filt[hp] = sig;
    sig *= c;
    sig += filt[bp];
    filt[bp] = sig;
    sig *= c;
    sig += filt[lp];
    filt[lp] = sig;
}

void read_impl(std::initializer_list<T*> inputs, std::initializer_list<T*> outputs, int len, std::integral_constant<state_var_type, state_var_type::single_out>) {

    auto inputIter = inputs.begin();
    auto outputIter = outputs.begin();

    T* input = *inputIter;
    T* output = *outputIter;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        step_vars();
        read_filter(input[i]);
        output[i] = last = filt[tap] * makeup; //optimize with vector?
    }
} //read selected filter type (default lowpass)
```

This is the original assembly code I got this topology from, if that is helpful to understanding the topology (rdax is read, wrax is write, mulx is multiply). This snippet runs on the input signal once per sample:

```
rdax    lpal,1
mulx    kf
rdax    lpbl,1
wrax    lpbl,-1
rdax    lpal,kq  ;Multiply by resonance.
rdax    temp,1
mulx    kf
rdax    lpal,1
wrax    lpal,0
rdax    lpbl,-1
rdax    temp,1
mulx    lbyp
rdax    lpbl,1
```

How can I find this formula?